# Getting an animated text landing spot to be the same on all devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a basic Jquery animate function to try to learn it. It seems straight forward so far, but the issue I am running into is that I want the wording to be aligned center horizontally/vertically in the container I have it in.

I tried setting the landing spot in the Jquery to 50%, but that is obviously starting the div at the 50% position. Now, if I would make it 40%, for example, that may work for one screen size, but not another. Now, normally I would just adjust my media queries for other screen types, but I am unsure how it would work with the landing destination defined in the Jquery.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this with the Jquery and changing the css to get this positioned in the same spot regardless of screen size?

```js
$(function() {
    $("#text_div").animate(
        {left : "50%"}, 500, function() {}
    );
});
```

```css
#container {
 margin: 20px 10%;
 height: 500px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 top: 70px;
}
#text_div {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
 top: 40%;
 clear: both;
 font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div id="text_div">My writing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you wanted your text to go to left:"50%", then your code is correct. 50% is always 50% no matter the size of your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#text_div").animate({
    left: "0"
  }, 500, function() {});
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px 10%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#text_div {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: -40%;
  top: 40%;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="text_div">My writing</div>
</div>
```

I used CSS3 flexbox to align your text to center.

Comment: The thing is, I won't actually want the words to appear at the exact center. I am trying to figure out how to get this to go to same spot regardless of location.

Comment: Is this the flexbox? `display: flex;
  justify-content: center;`. I have never even heard of it before.

Comment: flexbox is new introduction in css3 for layout purpose. yes you got the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually calculate the width of the containers that is `div` do an mathametical ops and set the value of `left` . It will be always independent of device screen size

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="text_div">My writing Here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
  margin:auto;
  width:500px;

}
#text_div {
    position: absolute;
    width:auto;
      top: 50%;
      font-size: 3em;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
 var a = ($("#container").width())/2- ($("#text_div").width())/2
  $("#text_div").animate(
        {left : a}, 500, function() {}
    );
});
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gzv2b6mw/1/)

The text will always be horizantally centered and you can do same to make it vertically centerd

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: The thing is, I won't actually want the words to appear at the exact center. I am trying to figure out how to get this to go to same spot regardless of location.

Comment: oh! what you mean by same spot? do you want to make it position:fixed?

Comment: No. I'm saying if I want it to go to `left: 85%;`, I want it to go to that same spot on all screen types.

Comment: oh! 85% will be different for every screen, So you need to use value in term of pixel